# USB WIreless adapter for Kali Linux VirtualBox

Tags: usb, networking, network-adapter, virtual-machines

I am in desperate need of a wireless adapter for Kali Linux. I run Kali Linux version 2019.2 on VirtualBox on a MacBook Air.

Any recommendations for a wireless adapter I can find (an have it shipped quickly if possible) to do wifi cracking? This is for a school project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Null Byte, via WonderHowTo, has a nice article on the best wireless adapters for Kali Linux. Here are the listed compatible chipsets:

> - Atheros AR9271
> - Ralink RT3070
> - Ralink RT3572
> - Realtek 8187L (Wireless G adapters)
> - Realtek RTL8812AU (newly in 2017)
> - my research also suggests the Ralink RT5370N is compatible

You can find direct purchase links (Amazon) in his article:

https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/buy-best-wireless-network-adapter-for-wi-fi-hacking-2019-0178550/